# array index out of bounds problems

Tags: objective-c, arrays

So I'm making a biginteger program, and I'm having a problem with adding two arrays that aren't the same length. The problem I'm having is with the add method. If I'm iterating through an array is there any way to test if element is out of bounds. I've tried testing if the element in a is equal to nil, but I still get the exception. Any help would be great thanks.

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "MPInteger.h"

    @implementation MPInteger

    {
    }

    -(id) initWithString: (NSString *) x
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            intString = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (int i = 0; i < [x length]; i++) {
                NSString *ch = [x substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
                [intString addObject:ch];

            }

        }

        return self;
    }

    -(NSString *) description
    {
        return self.description;
    }


    - (MPInteger *) add: (MPInteger *) x {
        NSMutableArray *a = self->intString;
        NSMutableArray *b = x->intString;
        NSMutableArray *c = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSInteger arrayCount;
        if (a < b) {
            arrayCount = [b count];
        } else {
            arrayCount = [a count];
        }
        int num = 10;
        int carry = 1;
        NSNumber *total;
        NSNumber *carrySum;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
            if (a[i] == nil) {

                total = @([b[i] intValue]);
                [c addObject:total];
            } else if (b[i] == nil) {
                total = @([a[i] intValue]);
                [c addObject:total];
            } else {
            total = @([a[i] intValue] + [b[i] intValue]);
            [c addObject:total];
            }
        }
        for (NSInteger j = [c count]-1; j >=0; j--) {
            if ([c[j] intValue] >= num) {
                total = @([c[j] intValue] - num);
                carrySum = @([c[j-1] intValue] + carry);
                [c replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:total];
                [c replaceObjectAtIndex:j-1 withObject: carrySum];
            }

        }
        NSString *str = [c componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@", str);

        return x;
    }

    -(MPInteger *) multiply: (MPInteger *) x
    {

        NSMutableArray *a = self->intString;
        NSMutableArray *b = x->intString;
        NSMutableArray *c = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *sum = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSNumber *total;
        NSNumber *carrySum;
        int num = 10;
        NSNumber *endZero = 0;
        NSInteger bottomCount = [b count]-1;
        while (bottomCount != -1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < [a count]; i++) {
                total = @([a[i] intValue] * [[b objectAtIndex:bottomCount] intValue]);
                if (bottomCount == [b count] -1) {
                    [c addObject:total];
                } else {
                    [c replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:total];
                }
            }


            for (NSInteger j = [c count]-1; j>=0; j--) {
                NSString *carry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [c[j] intValue]];
                NSString *carry2 = [carry substringToIndex:1];
                int carryFinal = [carry2 intValue];
                NSString *carry3 = [carry2 stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
                int carry4 = [carry3 intValue];

                if ([c[j] intValue] >= num) {
                    total = @([c[j] intValue] - carry4);
                    carrySum = @([c[j-1] intValue] + carryFinal);
                    [c replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:total];
                    [c replaceObjectAtIndex:j-1 withObject: carrySum];
                } else {
                    if(j == 0) {
                        if (bottomCount == [b count] -1) {
                            bottomCount = bottomCount - 1;
                            NSString *str = [c componentsJoinedByString:@""];
                            [sum addObject: str];
                        } else {
                            [c addObject:@([endZero intValue])];
                            bottomCount = bottomCount - 1;
                            NSString *str = [c componentsJoinedByString:@""];
                            [sum addObject: str];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        NSMutableArray *finalSum = [NSMutableArray array];
        MPInteger *ele1;
        MPInteger *ele2;
        MPInteger *eleSum;

        NSNumber *endZ= @(0);
        [finalSum insertObject:endZ atIndex:0];
        for (int k = 0; k < [sum count]; k++) {
            NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sum[k] intValue]];
            NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sum[k+1] intValue]];
            ele1 = [[MPInteger alloc] initWithString:str];
            ele2 = [[MPInteger alloc] initWithString:str2];
            eleSum = [ele1 add: ele2];
            NSLog(@"%@", eleSum);
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", sum);



            return self;
        }
```

Updated this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
            if (a[i] == nil) {

                total = @([b[i] intValue]);
                [c addObject:total];
            } else if (b[i] == nil) {
                total = @([a[i] intValue]);
                [c addObject:total];
            } else {
            total = @([a[i] intValue] + [b[i] intValue]);
            [c addObject:total];
            }
        }
```

has now become:

```
NSMutableArray *c = a.count > b.count ? [a mutableCopy] : [b mutableCopy];
NSArray *shortestArray = a.count > b.count ? b : a;

[shortestArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSNumber *currentNumber, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        c[idx] = @(currentNumber.integerValue + [c[idx] integerValue]);
        NSLog(@"%@", c[idx]);
}];
```

What I think I need to do is every index that is in array a and not b or vise versa, is add beginning zeros, but I don't know how to do that.

I printed out what it does after each iteration and it gives:

```
2013-09-02 12:31:42.630 Asgn1[42471:303] 5
2013-09-02 12:31:42.632 Asgn1[42471:303] 3
2013-09-02 12:31:42.632 Asgn1[42471:303] 1
And a final answer of:
2013-09-02 12:31:42.633 Asgn1[42471:303] 353
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the failing part where you merge the arrays.

Comment: you need to check if `i` is less than [array count] for the array in question.  You may also want to fill up the difference with zeroes, but not sure if that will be efficient for you

Comment: I was thinking about doing the zeroes thing, but I didn't know how I would do that.. But I'll try the checking the i against array count.

Comment: At least in one line of the `for (int k = 0; k < [sum count]; k++) {` loop you're accessing `sum[k+1]`, which is out-of-bound when `sum[k]` is on the last element.

Comment: Okay I fixed it, i just added a thing at the top if the arrays are different at the start just add zeros until they are the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code that is failing would it not be simpler to take a `mutableCopy` of the large array and then loop over the smaller array for the calculations?

Perhaps something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *c             = a.count > b.count ? [a mutableCopy] : [b mutableCopy];
NSArray        *shortestArray = a.count > b.count ? b : a;

[shortestArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSNumber *currentNumber, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  c[idx] = @(currentNumber.integerValue + [c[idx] integerValue]);
}];
```

Comment: @courtney have you looked at this solution at all?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at this code. I'm quite new to objective c, and I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. But I will try this code now and see if it helps.

Comment: Okay I tried your code on 123 + 23, and it does go over the entire block, but it gives me 353, is there anyway to enumerate backwards over an array?

Comment: There is a slightly different method on `NSArray` called `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` which you can pass the option `NSEnumerationReverse` to

Comment: Could you please show me how that method works? I've tried to look for examples, but I cannot find on that uses that argument.

Comment: Ok well it doesn't quite work yet, but thank you for the help :)

Comment: I think the issue is that it stills seems to add from left to right.

Comment: I'm not following... Can you update your original question with some context